# How does the system call fork return two different values?

Tags: operating-system, fork

I am taking an operating system class and implementing fork for one of the class projects.

The code looks basically like this.

1.Find an unused process
2.Copy over the virtual address data
3.Copy over the trap frame
4.Set the return value register(rax) to be 0
5.Set the child process to be runnable
6.Return child process' pid.

So my question is since the child process is the exact same as the parent, wouldn't pick up where it is fork(at line 4)? Then continue executing fork(line 5 & 6) and eventually return its own pid.

Answer (score 1):

The child process is an (almost) exact duplicate of its parent. The memory content of the parent is copied to the child, at the moment of creation.

However, the child has their own stack. Since return values are passed on the stack, fork() can return two different values, one in each process.